# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Rendered more hooks than during the previous render (React Interface GrandStack with ApolloClient)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, react-table, grandstack

I have an error that always occurs when I refresh my page (on localhost)
I use the GrandStack React Interface based on a Neo4J database and I wanted to create a table with data filters.
I used the code found right [here](https://www.akashmittal.com/gui-utility-to-generate-react-table-code/) (the complete code on CodeSandBox right [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering))

And it works perfectly fine until I use my data (using ApolloClient)

I declare the following query at the beginning:

```
const GET_INSTANCE = gql`
  {
    finalTab {
      classObject
      object
      classSubject
      subject
      relation
    }
  }
`
```

Then I define *const data* and return the following Table

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_INSTANCE)
  return (
    <Paper>
      {loading && !error && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && !loading && <p>Error</p>}
      {data && !loading && !error && (
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={React.useMemo(() => data.finalTab, [])}
        />
      )}
    </Paper>
  )
```

It does work and compile, but as soon as I refresh the page, it displays the following error :

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

And it points to this line : `data={React.useMemo(() => data.finalTab, [])}`

EDIT :
I also tried declaring the data before the return statement as follows:

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_INSTANCE)
  if (error) return <p>error</p>
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  const instances = data.finalTab
  const data1 = React.useMemo(() => instances, [])
```

And then only returning the table :

```
  return <Table columns={columns} data={data1} />
```

but I still get the error

And I can't seem to get what I did wrong,
Can somebody help ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_INSTANCE)
  const finalTab = React.useMemo(() => data.finalTab, [])
  return (
    <Paper>
      {loading && !error && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && !loading && <p>Error</p>}
      {data && !loading && !error && (
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={finalTab}
        />
      )}
    </Paper>
  )
```

`useMemo` is a hook that must be initialized before returning anything.

Comment: Thanks for the response, 
But I'm not really sure I get what you mean, when I look up useMemo in React documentation I don't see any syntax for useMemo initialization, how can I initialize this hook ?

Comment: When using hooks: useEffect / useCallback / useMemo etc ...
It should always be before returning anything. or you will get the error in your title. 
Just put your useMemo bellow your useQuery (like in my example).

Comment: From react documentation you can't use a hook with conditionnal operator.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks 
That why you should put your hooks before returning something.